# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" when running program in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have written a code to expand shortened url. The code works fine as a standalone program. But when I put it in Hadoop where I extract the url in Map function, I get the following error. I have mentioned all httpclient dependencies in the classpath while compiling the code. Please help me.

```
14/07/28 08:16:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1405534657345_0008_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.myorg.ExtractUrl.unshortenSingleLevel(ExtractUrl.java:80)
    at org.myorg.ExtractUrl.unshorten(ExtractUrl.java:118)
    at org.myorg.ExtractUrl$Map.map(ExtractUrl.java:40)
    at org.myorg.ExtractUrl$Map.map(ExtractUrl.java:27)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

Comment: Jar which you have created does not contain this class.
Try running the standalone program from the jar created and then use it in hadoop command.You may also need at least HttpClient jar-library. You can get it at Apache Commons web-site.

Comment: I had added httpclient in classpath while compiling.

Comment: I added httpclient, httpcore, etc. to the jar file's classpath. Still same error

Comment: @ananyachoudhury Use `-libjars [...]` command line argument.  See http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html

Comment: Thanks climbage. Your clue gave me a direction. I solved the problem. Referred http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/